# Python and BigQuery doesn't work on 'repeated' field with Nones

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to add a JSON data through the google.cloud BigQuery package.

Where the schema is not mapped (`autodetect=True`, `schema_update_options="ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION"`).

It works perfectly until I get a nested object like the attached object

```
{'most_recent_voyage': {'eta': None, 'destination': 'HONG KONG',
                        'matched_port': {'unlocode': 'HK HKG', 'port_name': 'Hong Kong',
                                         'center_point': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [None, None]}}}}
```

After investigating a bit I found out that it does work if I put float objects in `coordinates` instead of `None, None`.

How can I solve this one and what might be the problem?

Comment: Numpy floats or native floats? Do other non-None data types work? What does the BQ schema look like when passing None, None?

Comment: You might also want to review this page: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated